# ArcGIS Online & Mobile Apps Projection Support?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, arcgis-platform, arcgis-collector

What is the level of projection/co-ordinate system and transformation support accross the ArcGIS Online family of apps ;

- ArcGIS Online Web Map Viewer (Desktop)
- ArcGIS Online Web Map Viewer (Mobile)
- ArcGIS for Windows Mobile
- ArcGIS for Android / iOS
- ArcGIS Collector

Is there any documentation or a support matrix such as ESRI provide for data sources ?

Comment: Would be nice if ESRI support published this information publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Experimenting with self hosted tiled map services in British National Grid (EPSG:27700) support for that seems variable:

### Supported

- ArcGIS Online Web Map Viewer (Desktop)
- ArcGIS for Windows Mobile **(however transformations not applied to GPS data)**
- ArcGIS for Android **(however transformations not applied to GPS data)**

### Not Supported

- ArcGIS Online Web Map Viewer (Mobile)
- ArcGIS Collector